# out of memory error on replication slot in postgresql 11

Tags: postgresql

The problem is shown here: https://www.enterprisedb.com/postgres-tutorials/postgres-13-logicaldecodingworkmem-and-how-it-saves-your-server-going-out-memory

The solution that PostgreSQL give us is use the logical_decoding_work_mem configuration parameter.

My problem is that I use PostgreSQL 11 and logical_decoding_work_mem solution is not available in this version.

How do I limit the memory usage of walsenders in PostgreSQL 11?

Comment: You will have to upgrade.

Comment: I cant upgrade the server.

Answer (score -1):

Go into your postgresql.conf

The default value for this parameter, which is set in postgresql.conf, is:

```
#shared_buffers = 128MB
```

You should increase this to 20% of your servers ram.

work_mem (integer)
The work_mem parameter basically provides the amount of memory to be used by internal sort operations and hash tables before writing to temporary disk files. Sort operations are used for order by, distinct, and merge join operations. Hash tables are used in hash joins and hash based aggregation.

The default value for this parameter, which is set in postgresql.conf, is:

#work_mem = 4MB

Setting the correct value of work_mem parameter can result in less disk-swapping, and therefore far quicker queries.

We can use the formula below to calculate the optimal work_mem value for the database server:

```
Total RAM * 0.25 / max_connections
```

The max_connections parameter is one of the GUC parameters to specify the maximum number of concurrent connections to the database server. By default it is set to 100 connections.

We can also directly assign work_mem to a role:

```
postgres=# alter user test set work_mem='4GB';

ALTER ROLE
```

maintenance_work_mem (integer)

The maintenance_work_mem parameter basically provides the maximum amount of memory to be used by maintenance operations like vacuum, create index, and alter table add foreign key operations.

The default value for this parameter, which is set in `postgresql.conf`, is:

#maintenance_work_mem = 64MB

It’s recommended to set this value higher than work_mem; this can improve performance for vacuuming. In general it should be:

```
Total RAM * 0.05
```

effective_cache_size (integer)

The effective_cache_size parameter estimates how much memory is available for disk caching by the operating system and within the database itself. The PostgreSQL query planner decides whether it’s fixed in RAM or not. Index scans are most likely to be used against higher values; otherwise, sequential scans will be used if the value is low. Recommendations are to set Effective_cache_size at 50% of the machine’s total RAM.